# Connecting blue "C" wire to gas furnace, but furnace already has white wire?

Tags: thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire, nest

sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm trying to install a smart thermostat (Nest). I realized that while there was an unused blue "C" wire behind my old thermostat, it was not connected to the furnace on the other end.

However when I opened up my furnace, I see that there is already a white wire inserted in one of the "C" slots. Can I just insert the blue wire in the other slot? What is this white wire for?

Other details - I have a two-zone central air/forced air w/ 2 gas furnaces setup. Both thermostats have this unused blue wire. I'm currently trying to setup the thermostat located in the 1st floor which is hooked up to the furnace in the basement. The house is a new 2020 construction. Thanks!

Circuit photo (blue wire hidden behind front most yellow wire)
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your zone board please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Where do I typically find the zone board?

Comment: The zone board, sadly, can be just about anywhere, although it's common to park it in a mechanical space. You'll have to follow the thermostat cable from the furnace to find it..

Answer (score 0):

The white wire plugged in to the c on the board it’s the common load for the condenser unit.. so you could also insert the the blue wire also into the C terminal that will give a 24volt common that is required to run your nest .. then you will also have to connect the common in the dual zone control also